# Method to copy a stack into a new one and return it without changing the original stack using a single queue using standard API classes

Tags: java, stack, queue

Ok, so I tried making a method that does what I wrote in the title. It should be pretty clear to see what's happening. However, I feel like I'm making it more complicated than it should be. I copy the stack into the queue, resulting in it being backwards: `[4,3,2,1]`
Then I copy it back into the stack, and then back into the queue so that I can get it in proper order: `[1,2,3,4]`
Then I peek into the copiedStack, and remove into the original stack.
Then I return the copiedStack.
My main method prints this:
`[1,2,3,4]
[1,2,3,4]`

^ (btw, anyone know how to properly align the code above? it's annoying me)

So is there a simpler implementation?

The methods I can use are here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

```
import java.util.*;

public class Question2Stack {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    stack.push(1);
    stack.push(2);
    stack.push(3);
    stack.push(4);
    System.out.println(copyStack(stack));
    System.out.println(stack);
  }

  public static Stack<Integer> copyStack(Stack<Integer> stack) {
    Stack<Integer> copiedStack = new Stack<Integer>();
    Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
      q.add(stack.pop());
    }
    while (!q.isEmpty()) {
      stack.push(q.remove());
    }
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
      q.add(stack.pop());
    }
    while (!q.isEmpty()) {
      copiedStack.push(q.peek());
      stack.push(q.remove());
    }
    return copiedStack;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack is a `Collection`, and collections can [`addAll(Collection)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

```
Stack<Integer> intStackCopy = new Stack<Integer>();
intStackCopy.addAll(origStack);
```

You can also simply iterate:

```
Iterator<Integer> intItr = origStack.iterator();
while(intItr.hasNext())  {
   intStackCopy.push(intItr.next());
}
```

If you absolutely have to use a 'Queue':

```
public Stack<Integer> copyStack(Stack<Integer> orig)  {
   Queue<Integer> q = new Queue<Integer>();
   q.addAll(orig);
   Stack<Integer> intStackCopy = new Stack<Integer>();
   intStackCopy.addAll(q);
   return  intStackCopy;
}
```

You can do this redundant `Queue` with any of the approaches in my or @Chamil's answer. The original does not need to be restored in any way, because it is never altered.

Comment: I don't think I'm allowed to use that. That's what I meant by standard API classes. I will add the links of what I believe I'm allowed to use to the question

Comment: Both of these methods are in the http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html webpage as you specify. They are listed under "Methods inherited from class java.util.Vector".

Comment: Write a method copyStack that takes as argument a stack S and returns a new stack containing the same elements and in the same order as S. Before the method ﬁnishes, it must restore the
contents of S to its original state (same contents in the same order). Besides the new stack that the method returns, the only additional data structure that it can use is a single queue.

Comment: And `clone`, for that matter, is also on that webpage, and also under "Methods inherited from class java.util.Vector".

Comment: I'm sorry, but this makes no sense. Both of the approaches in my answer, in addition to the `clone` method from the other answer, can fulfill your requirements.

Comment: I just don't get why my teacher would say we can only use a single queue if we weren't supposed to use it. She also said we need to make sure that the contents of S are restored to their original state. I know your answer makes sense but I'm not sure why the wording of my teacher makes it seem like I can't do it like you did. I will try and double check with her. Based on my implementation though, using the methods I used, is there a simpler way?

Comment: You said to @Chamil: "I'm fairly certain I can't simply clone it because my teacher said that we can use a single queue in the method". You're saying although you need to duplicate an object, you're only allowed to use a single object? That makes no sense. (I'm assuming you mean "Stack" when you say "queue".) You have been provided three very simple ways to duplicate a stack without altering the original. What more do you need?

Comment: I've written the question in my 2nd reply to your answer. In the question it says write a method that takes as an argument stack S and returns a NEW stack. At the end, she writes "Besides the new stack that the method returns, the only additional data structure that it can use is a single queue". I don't see what's so confusing.

Comment: Updated my answer. All of these approaches create a new stack, as required, including clone.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to figure out why she worded it that way and then do it the most efficient way that I'm allowed. Appreciate it.

Comment: this is what a Teacher Assistant replied: I'm not familiar with addAll(). That might work. Clone is interesting. You'll learning more about it in 303. In order to use clone, you basically have to implement it yourself. By default is does a 'shallow copy', which basically means if you have an object A which points to object B, only object A will be copied. The contents of B won' t be. In order to use it properly, you have to know in advance what objects are being cloned. 
You can try addAll() and see if it works. I wouldn't be surprised if it also does a shallow copy.

Comment: do you have any reply to that? is she right?

Answer (score 0):

```
Stack<Integer> copiedStack = (Stack)intStack.clone();
```

The Stack class implements clonable interface. the clone method will clone your stack and return the reference to the new stack.

Comment: I don't think I'm allowed to use that. That's what I meant by standard API classes. I will add the links of what I believe I'm allowed to use to the question

Comment: .close is a method of Object, so it's standard.

Comment: Please check what I updated my question with. And I'm fairly certain I can't simply clone it because my teacher said that we can use a single queue in the method

Comment: the Clonable interface comes under java.lang package which contains all the java basic classes. Also the clone method is a standard in java. Anybody working with java must know thie clone method very well.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html is one of the thing you can use. So it has the clone method. whats wrong?

Comment: The way my teacher worded the question is what's wrong. "Write a method copyStack that takes as argument a stack S and returns a new stack containing the same elements and in the same order as S. Before the method ﬁnishes, it must restore the contents of S to its original state (same contents in the same order). Besides the new stack that the method returns, the only additional data structure that it can use is a single queue."

Comment: I'm not saying your answer is wrong, just that the way my teacher worded it makes it seem like we need to restore stack S back to it's original order, and that we can only use a single queue in the method (which I'm assuming means we need to use a queue)

Comment: There's nothing to restore, because clone, and the two approaches in my answer, ***do not alter the original object***.

Comment: I feel like my teacher is getting at the fact that we do need to alter the original object is what I am saying. I'll just e-mail her and ask, but I seriously do not understand why she would word the question like she did if we could just write a 1-liner method.